# What does code number mean in unhandled signals?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, signals

I run a custom GNU/Linux distro on an RISC-V Ariane CVA6 processor running on a custom design on an FPGA.

I am getting a bus error when I try to read from a memory mapped I/O register. I have verified that the mapping and address are correct.

When I run `dmesg` I see an unhandled signal 7 code 0x2 error popping up. I looked up the unhandled signal number [here](https://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/courses/moved.Building/signals.pdf) but I cannot find any reference to the code 0x2. Any ideas?

Comment: I would guess that there is a misalignment of an address. But if you say the address is correct, then I guess that absolutely can't be the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning of this code is architecture-specific. For RISC-V, the code that emits this message is in [`do_trap` in `arch/riscv/kernel/traps.c`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.15/source/arch/riscv/kernel/traps.c#L66). Signal 7 is `SIGBUS` (https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.15/source/include/uapi/asm-generic/signal.h#L18) (some older architectures have different signal numbers). For SIGBUS, the codes are [`BUS_xxx` constants](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.15/source/include/uapi/asm-generic/siginfo.h#L246). 2 is `BUS_ADRERR`: “non-existent physical address”, raised by [`mm_fault_error`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.15/source/arch/riscv/mm/fault.c#L61).

So there's something wrong with your mapping. Maybe you filled the MMU incorrectly, or maybe you didn't fill the MMU table for the correct context. This is way beyond the expertise of Unix.SE. If the problem is MMU management in the Linux kernel, you may find help on Stack Overflow **if you post complete code**. If the problem is configuring peripherals on RISC-V, a forum with RISC-V experts is probably a better place.

Comment: Turns out that a previous unmap function released more pages than intended and that why I got the bus error.

As for the exact status code I read more on RISC-V privileged manual: https://riscv.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/riscv-privileged-v1.10.pdf. Looking up on the case register error codes the corresponding code of the bus error I got was a Load page fault.